# How to get logged in user in django views across different apps

Tags: python, django, view, request

I have a django application called 'main'. user authentication and everything seems fine. And I created a new app called 'upload' from startapp command.
user can login on 'main' app but I can not get the logged in user from request.user on views of another app ('upload' app). It returns Anonymous user all the time. any way to get the logged in user? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If applications placed in one project (work in one site) doesn't matter what application.
But if applications runs in different sites you need, for example, shared between sites session storage and, i think, user table.